# Use [construct] tag instead of [construct-2]

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm using Construct 3 a lot and I noticed that there are [very few questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct-2) about Construct here, under the [construct-2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct-2) tag. Most of these questions, obviously, refer to Construct 2, its previous, obsolete version.

I believe that renaming the tag to [construct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct) and creating a synonym from [construct-2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct-2) could attract more public. I don't think we'd need two tags even if we had more traffic.

I know there are very few people interested, apparently, but it might be a kind of egg-chicken situation, because lacking a proper tag can discourage prospective users.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing that often works well for this kind of topic is to post an answer offering a proposed solution, even if it's not one you're sure about, then folks can up-vote it if they like it, or it can spur them to post alternative solutions if they don't.

Comment: Thank you. It makes a lot of sense. I was being cautious because I'm not active on this site and my privileges are ridiculously low. :-) I'll make a bold edit by turning my "wondering if" sentence into an actual proposal.

Comment: I'd recommend putting proposals in answers - that way folks can upvote their favourite proposal out of multiple, separately from upvoting the question as a good question to discuss.

Comment: AFAIK, we typically create version specific tags when there are significant differences in architecture and API that would make answers specific to a version irrelevant for another version. This practice _may be_ irrelevant in the case of low-traffic tags.

Answer (score 1):

Proposal:

- New [construct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct) tag used for Construct 3 and for the rare legacy question about Construct 2.
- All questions tagged as [construct-2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct-2) to be re-tagged as [construct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construct).

No need for synonyms and version-based tagging actually.

Rationale for keeping Construct 2 and 3 together: Construct 2 is obsolete and incompatible with Construct 3, but at the same time many techniques and tricks are overlapping. Remember that this is visual programming, therefore even if the project files are incompatible the solutions can be similar.